# Graphic Design book for an artist that would like to study graphic design

Tags: book, education

I would like to give (gift) a book to a friend which studied art for many years and is thinking about studying graphic design.

I know pretty much stuff about web design, having read books, articles and guides, I know that good web design books always explain a bit of graphic design too, but usually they're more specific to web stuff.

I'd like to give her a book which is more about graphic design in general (she likes illustration) informative, practical and inspiring.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check out [Creative Workshop](http://www.amazon.com/Creative-Workshop-Challenges-Sharpen-Design/dp/1600617972/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1354212997&sr=8-1&keywords=creative+design). Just FYI, this really isn't a question for SE :)

Answer (score 2):

The newest edition of [Meggs' History of Graphic Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470168730) came out recently. It's great as far as a historical textbook goes.

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568989830) addresses the question of how to be a designer.

All of [Tufte's books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961392177) are very informative but  a bit dense and overly scholarly.